# HTML table column width does not appear as expected

Tags: html, css

I am simply trying to equally display three images in a row. But with the following code, the first two images occupy about `45%` each and the third image is extremely small. Why?

```
<table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="33%">
                    <img src="image1.png" style="width:100%;">
                    <p>Image Name 1</p>
            </td>
            <td width="33%">
                    <img src="image2.png" style="width:100%;">
                    <p>Image Name 2</p>    
            </td>
            <td width="34%">
                    <img src="image3.png" style="width:100%;">
                    <p>Image Name 3</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table
```

Comment: What are the sizes of the images?

Comment: Is this the only code on your page? Do you have any style sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `<table>` for this, try using `<div>`s and change `width` to `max-width`:

```css
.cols {overflow: hidden;}
.cols .col-33 {width: 33.33%; float: left;}
```

```html
<div class="cols">
  <div class="col-33">
    <img src="//placehold.it/500x50?text=Image+1" style="max-width:100%;">
    <p>Image Name 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-33">
    <img src="//placehold.it/250x50?text=Image+2" style="max-width:100%;">
    <p>Image Name 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-33">
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x50?text=Image+3" style="max-width:100%;">
    <p>Image Name 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```